# How to get any type array field from alamofire response?

Tags: swift, alamofire, decodable

I have such field in my json response:

```
"title": [2402, "Dr.", "Prof.", "Prof. Dr.", "HM"]
```

And I would like to parse it. I have my model class:

```
struct AppDataModel:Decodable {
    ...
    let title = Dictionary<String,Any>()
    
    
    enum CodingKeys: String,CodingKey{
        case title
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

As you can see I tried to use `Dictionary<String,Any>()` for it. And also I thought about array of Any -> `[Any]` but I usually get such error:

```
Type 'AppDataModel' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
```

I think that I have to process it like an ordinary json. But I didn't find such data type in Swift, only dictionary. So, maybe someone knows how to process such response fields?

Comment: You cannot decode a heterogenous array unless you decode it in code and handle the different types properly.

Comment: @vadian, so how I can solve this problem? I thought about json processing but it is impossible as I saw

Comment: There are multiple ways, the solution depends on your needs. For example is the leading integer relevant?

Comment: This integer is translation string id for these strings, so it can be changed. As for my needs - I need only get string data without integer number

Comment: Implement `init(from decoder`, decode `title` as `unkeyedContainer`, pull out the values, drop the first and assign the rest to a `[String]` type

Comment: can you please give some more details in your answer please, because I still have some difficulties with your last comment?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example to decode a single key as heterogenous array

```
let jsonString = """
{"title": [2402, "Dr.", "Prof.", "Prof. Dr.", "HM"], "name":"Foo"}
"""

struct AppDataModel : Decodable {
    let titles : [String]
    let name : String
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case title, name }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        var titlesContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .title)
        var titleArray = [String]()
        let _ = try titlesContainer.decode(Int.self) // decode and drop the leading integer
        while !titlesContainer.isAtEnd { // decode all following strings
            titleArray.append(try titlesContainer.decode(String.self))
        }
        titles = titleArray
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(AppDataModel.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: in my init scope I see such error `Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties`, what I have to show you and maybe you will help me?

Comment: maybe it is connected with that I have some other keys in this model?

Comment: My example contains only one key. If there are more you have to decode each key in a separate line. I updated the answer with a second key.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct AppDataModel: Codable {
    let title: [Title]?
}

extension AppDataModel {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try newJSONDecoder().decode(AppDataModel.self, from: data)
    }

    init(_ json: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws {
        guard let data = json.data(using: encoding) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "JSONDecoding", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        }
        try self.init(data: data)
    }

    init(fromURL url: URL) throws {
        try self.init(data: try Data(contentsOf: url))
    }

    func with(
        title: [Title]?? = nil
    ) -> AppDataModel {
        return AppDataModel(
            title: title ?? self.title
        )
    }

    func jsonData() throws -> Data {
        return try newJSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

    func jsonString(encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws -> String? {
        return String(data: try self.jsonData(), encoding: encoding)
    }
}

enum Title: Codable {
    case integer(Int)
    case string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .integer(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Title.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for Title"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .integer(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

func newJSONDecoder() -> JSONDecoder {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return decoder
}

func newJSONEncoder() -> JSONEncoder {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return encoder
}

//use

do {
    let appDataModel = try AppDataModel(json)
}
catch{
    //handle error
}
```